# Possible to have more than SwingWorker thread in one class?

Tags: java, multithreading

Is it possible to have more than one swingworker thread in one class or would I have to make an adapter class for each thread and then make an object of that adapter class?

E.g. I have a button called throw. When the button is pressed, It runs the rollHuman(); method and rollComputer(); method through the use of the actionListener(). The methods are in my main class and the actionlistner is in another class (not using anonymous classes for the actionlistenr). These method pretty much rolls 5 dices and  displays them on the frame. What I want to do is to make the methods have its own thread.

I've tried extending the SwingWorker abstract class in my main class but released that wouldn't work as i'd only be able to override the toDoInBackground() method only once hence I won't be able to have the roll methods in individual threads.

Comment: Yes, you can create and use as many SwingWorkers as you want. Why couldn't you? Why don't you try?

Comment: Why do you even need threads? Are the `rollXXX()` functions computationally expensive?